# Ruby on rails: If else in controller issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, controller

So I am having an issue with an if else statement in the controller. I have 4 radiobuttons on my page and one hidden field. There are also 4 divs where only one can be visible at a time.When a different radiobutton is checked another div is shown. This should work like a 'complex' search interface. In the hidden field I'm inserting a value from 1 to 4 (depending on what radio button is checked). In the controller I'm looking at the value of the hidden field and my functions should change accordingly. My problem is that it does not work. I tried a couple of different things but didn't find an answer to my problem.

Here's my code

### View:

```
<div>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'searchRBN', 'patient', true, :onchange => "checkRadioButton()" %>
    <%= label_tag :byPatient_patient, "Patient" %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'searchRBN', 'staff', false, :onchange => "checkRadioButton()" %>
    <%= label_tag :byStaff_staff, "Staff" %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'searchRBN', 'ocmw', false, :onchange => "checkRadioButton()" %>
    <%= label_tag :byOcmw_ocmw, "OCMW" %>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'searchRBN', 'mutuality', false, :onchange => "checkRadioButton()" %>
    <%= label_tag :byMutuality_mutuality, "Mutuality" %>
</div>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:hidden_one, "1") %>
<div id="searchByPatient">
    <%= form_tag patients_path, :method => 'get' do %>
        <p>
            <%= text_field_tag :search1, params[:search1] %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div id="searchByStaff" class="notVisible">
    <%= form_tag patients_path, :method => 'get' do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search2, params[:search2] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

### Controller:

```
  def index
    @staff_all = Staff.all
    @ocmw_all = Ocmw.all
    @mutuality_all = Mutuality.all

    if params[:hidden_one] == '1'
      @patients = Patient.searchByName(params[:search1])
    elsif params[:hidden_one] == '2'
      @patients = Patient.searchByStaff(params[:search2])
    else
      @patients = Patient.all
    end
  end
```

### In my model:

```
  def self.searchByName(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end

  def self.searchByStaff(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['marriedTo LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

Mathias A.

Comment: Do you set the "value" of hidden_one field before you submit? Otherwise, the value of params[:hidden_one] will always be 1. What do you have on the rails logs, which parameters are being submited? Its probably an issue with the values being submited.

Comment: Also you should post your javascript method `checkRadioButton()` too.

Comment: @rorra, the value is set in the index page at "1" and than I'm just changing it through the `checkRadioButton()` function

Comment: Here's the function (part of it, I know it can be achieved in a better way, just keeping it like this until it works fine):  if(rbnPatient.checked)
 {
  document.getElementById('hidden_one').setAttribute('value', '1');
  document.getElementById('searchByPatient').setAttribute('class', 'visible');
  
  document.getElementById('searchByStaff').setAttribute('class', 'notVisible');
  document.getElementById('searchByOcmw').setAttribute('class', 'notVisible');
  document.getElementById('searchByMutuality').setAttribute('class', 'notVisible');
 }

Comment: No one has another idea ? I managed to find my problem, I can't acces the value of my hidden field tag, it is always nil.

Answer (score 1):

I think your hidden field is outside of your form tag so it will be never submitted to the server.

Another solution would be to simply put a hidden field to each search form you have to identify the corresponding search form on the server.

Example:

```
<div id="searchByPatient">
<%= form_tag patients_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :search_type, :search_by_patient %>
    <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search1, params[:search1] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>
</div>
```